# unity manager and top panel is not visible in ubuntu 16.04

Tags: unity, panel

In ubuntu 16.04 after I installed some packages, unity manager and top panel is not visible. I tried the following:

sudo dconf reset -f /org/compiz

setsid unity

I am getting messages like the following:

setsid unity

unity-panel-service stop/waiting

unity7 stop/waiting

unity-panel-service start/running, process 2330

unity7 start/running, process 2451

. I tried to install ubuntu desktop and unity, but no success. Please suggest what to do.